# How to apply two general rules to Google Drive sharing?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

In G Suite's Google Drive, I can set my folder's permissions to:

1. Anyone who has the link can view, or
2. Anyone at Your Organization who has the link can edit (add, edit, and organize)

I want both, and they're not conceptually incompatible, but I can't figure out a way to configure this in the *Share* menu. Well, actually, I want:

- Anyone who has the link can view, and
- Anyone at Your Organization who has the link can add.

When I've tried this so far, I have two issues:

1. The two rules are mutually exclusive. If I set rule (1) and then rule (2), rule (2) replaces rule (1). I can add as many individuals as I want, but I can only pick one general rule like these.
2. There's no option to allow *add* without also allowing *organize* and *edit*.

How can I get all or part of what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the option anyone with the link can view use the included dropdown.

For the option anyone in your organization can edit, share the folders with a group that include all the members of your organization and set it to edit. Maybe you should ask you organization admin for

- the group email address,
- create such group for you,
- enable the related option in Google Groups for Business so you could create the group even if you aren't a G Suite admin